# Install Fedora with VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, fedora

I use Ubuntu 22.04 and I installed VirtualBox in order to test other Linux distributions...As mentioned in the title, I would like to test Fedora on VirtualBox. I watched several tutorials and I did some research on the internet but I only found explanations on how to install Fedora with VirtualBox on Windows and not on Ubuntu...
Does anyone know how to install Fedora on VirtualBox with Ubuntu 22.04 as host OS?
(My apologies for my bad English!)

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: The procedure is the same. The virtualbox interface is almost identical in Ubuntu and Windows.

Comment: Try it. If you get stuck, you can ask questions about Fedora in https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Hi Archisman Panigrahi!

The problem I encountered is that I had to download an iso file of Fedora and that I never succeeded in using this iso file with VirtualBox whereas in the tutorials intended for the users of VirtualBox on Windows PCs, the handling worked!
Indeed, each time I tried to open a new virtual machine, VirtualBox did not recognize the Fedora iso file while on the tutorials explaining the handling with VirtualBox on Windows, VirtualBox recognized the Fedora iso file and Fedora was launched!
I know I could use this iso file to install it on a usb key and test Fedora by booting my pc on the key but for practical reasons, I would prefer to test Fedora with VirtualBox...

Anyway, if someone has a solution or an idea to submit to me so that I can boot Fedora with VirtualBox, it would be welcome! :)

Thanks Archisman Panigrahi!
(And everyone else)